# Minimal number of generators of an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

> In the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, I should prove that the ideal
>   $$I=(\underbrace{x^4-y^3}_{=:\,p_1},\underbrace{x^5-z^3}_{=:\,p_2},\underbrace{y^5-z^4}_{=:\,p_3})$$
>   can not be generated by two elements.

I showed that $I\neq (p_1,p_2)$, $I\neq (p_1,p_3)$, $I\neq (p_2,p_3)$. Is it enough to conclude? If I was working with linear subspaces it would be, but I don't know if things works in the same way with ideals.

Comment: No, it is not enough. One must prove that $I$ can not be generated by ANY two elements.

Comment: @BorisNovikov Thank you! And have you any idea on how to prove it? I add what I already know about $I$

Comment: No, I don't know. Maybe a Gröbner basis will be helpful?

Comment: In response to your edit, I don't believe the ideal you have gives $\mathbb C[u^3, u^4, u^5]$ as the quotient.  See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483589/how-to-compute-iy-for-a-curve-y-defined-parametrically-by-x-t3-y-t/483654?noredirect=1#comment1042384_483654).

Comment: @Jim Thank you! It seems you are right YACP :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $R=\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]$ as a graded ring by assigning to the indeterminates the following degrees: $\deg X=3$, $\deg Y=4$, $\deg Z=5$. (This way the ideal $I$ becomes homogeneous.) If $\mathfrak m=(X,Y,Z)$, then the minimal number of generators of $I$ is $\dim_{\mathbb C}I/\mathfrak mI$. Can you show that the residue classes of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ modulo $\mathfrak mI$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know how to compute those residue classes. And why one needs to work with a homogeneous ideal?

Comment: If the ideal isn't homogeneous I don't think this claim is necessarily true: "the minimal number of generators of $I$ is $\dim_{\mathbb C}I/\mathfrak mI$" since in this case $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal among others, but when we introduce a grading then $\mathfrak m$ becomes the maximal homogeneous ideal of $R$. (You don't need to compute some residue classes, only to prove that them are linearly independent which is easy enough if take into account the grading.)